# Distribution: $f_a(x)=\frac{H(x+a)-H(x-a)}{2a}$. What is its derivative with respect to the parameter $a$ and the limit as $a\to 0$.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, distribution-theory

Consider the distribution

$$ f_a(x)=\frac{H(x+a)-H(x-a)}{2a}$$

Determine the $a$-derivative of this distribution

$$ \left <  \frac{\partial f_a}{\partial a},\phi \right> = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{ \left <f_{a+h} ,\phi \right > - \left <f_{a} ,\phi \right > }{h}$$

and the limit

$$ \lim_{a\to 0} \frac{\partial f_a}{\partial  a}$$

My partial answer can be found below.

Answer (score 1):

We consider that we have 
$$ \langle f_{a+h},\phi\rangle-\langle f_a,\phi\rangle= \frac{1}{2(a+h)}\int_{-a-h}^{a+h} \phi(x)dx-\frac{1}{2a}\int_{-a}^{a} \phi(x)dx$$ 
Combining the fractions, 
$$ = \frac{1}{2a(a+h)}\left ( a\int_{-a-h}^{a+h} \phi(x)dx-(a+h)\int_{-a}^{a} \phi(x)dx \right) $$
Splitting the integrals,

$$ = \frac{1}{2a(a+h)}\left ( a\int_{-a-h}^{-a} \phi(x)dx
+a\int_{-a}^{a} \phi(x)dx
+a\int_{a}^{a+h} \phi(x)dx 
-a\int_{-a}^{a} \phi(x)dx-h\int_{-a}^{a} \phi(x)dx \right )$$

Cancelling, 
$$ = \frac{1}{2a(a+h)}\left ( a\int_{-a-h}^{-a} \phi(x)dx
+a\int_{a}^{a+h} \phi(x)dx 
-h\int_{-a}^{a} \phi(x)dx \right )$$

So if we divide by $h$ and let $h\to 0$, we get $\frac{0}{0}$, so we may use L'Hopital's rule to get

$$ \left <\frac{\partial f_a}{\partial  a},\phi\right >=\lim_{h\to 0} 2(a+2h)^{-1}a^{-1}\left ( a \phi(-a-h)+
a\phi(a+h)-\int_{-a}^{a} \phi(x)dx \right ) $$

Yielding

$$ \left <\frac{\partial f_a}{\partial  a},\phi\right >=  \frac{ a \phi(-a)+
a\phi(a)-\int_{-a}^{a} \phi(x)dx }{2a^2} $$

or

$$\frac{\partial f_a}{\partial  a}= \frac{ a\delta(x+a)+a\delta(x-a)
-2af_a }{2a^2} $$

That concludes part 1.  Intuitively, I would have expected $-\delta(x-a)$, but this is what I have.  Did I miss a negative sign?

So now what is the limit as $a\to 0$?

$$\lim_{a\to0 }\frac{\partial f_a}{\partial  a}= \lim_{a\to0 }\frac{ a \phi(-a)+
a\phi(a)-\int_{-a}^{a} \phi(x)dx }{2a^2} $$

Using L'Hopital's rule again,

$$= \lim_{a\to0 }\frac{\phi(-a)+a\phi'(-a)(-1) +
\phi(a)+a\phi'(a)-\phi(a)+\phi(-a)(-1) }{4a} $$

Cancelling,

$$= \lim_{a\to0 }\frac{a\phi'(-a)(-1) +a\phi'(a) }{4a} $$

or

$$= \lim_{a\to0 }\frac{\phi'(a) -\phi'(-a)}{4}=\frac{\phi'(0) -\phi'(0)}{4}=0 $$

Intuitively, I would have expected $\delta'(x)$, but this is the answer I have. Do you agree?